# Is there an alternative to jai-imageio for pdfbox?

Tags: pdfbox, javax.imageio

I'm using PDFBox to convert PDFs to image. Some of the documents are rendered incomplete or completely blank.

According to the documentation I would need JAI ImageIO to add support for JPEG2000 images.
The problem is that those libraries are very old/abandoned so our system admin doesn't want to import them.

Is there a more recent alternative?

Comment: I'm afraid this question is off-topic for SO. Try [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) instead. Perhaps [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/23304) is useful. 

Comment: Thank you @HaraldK. I didn't know there was a community for that!